# How to calculate fields to search data within a set of unique identifier from another field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, modelbuilder, python-parser

I want to know how I should go about coding this table to get the 'context" score for each unique identifier (UI). Each unique identifier has a polygon with non remnant area, remnant area and regrowth area and depending on the ratio of this vegetation type it gets a certain score (See rules above)

[image: Attribute Table]

[image: Rules to calculate site context]

I want to know how I should go about coding this table to get the 'context" score for each unique identifier (UI). Each unique identifier has a polygon with non remnant , remnant, and regrowth areas, and depending on the ratio of this vegetation type it gets a score (See rules below)

I tried to make it so the different vegetation conditions are in there own fields, then perhaps find the max area within the UI for each condition. This will then make it so all condition areas are in one row to calculate the context per row, however I don't know how to achieve this.

**Code**

```
def calcSC(Remnant_Area, Regrowth_Area,):
   if Remnant_Area >= 200:
      return 10
  elif ((sum([Remnant_Area >=100 and Remnant_Area])) <200):
      return 7
  elif (Remnant_Area+ Regrowth_Area)>200:
      return 7
  elif Regrowth_Area >200:
      return 7
  elif (Remnant_Area >=25 and Remnant_Area <100):
      return 5
  elif ((sum([Remnant_Area,Regrowth_Area]))>=25) and ((sum([Remnant_Area,Regrowth_Area]))>=200): 
      return 5
  elif Regrowth_Area>=25 and Regrowth_Area<200:
      return 5
  elif (Remnant_Area >=5) and (Remnant_Area <25):
      return 2
  elif (Regrowth_Area >=5) and (Regrowth_Area <25):
      return 2
  elif (((sum([Remnant_Area,Regrowth_Area]))>=5) and ((sum([Remnant_Area,Regrowth_Area]))<25)): 
      return 2
  else:
      return 0
calcSC( !Remnant_Area!, !Regrowth_Area!)
```

Comment: Dissolve on unique identifier with max statistic for non remnant , remnant, and regrowth areas. So you get one record per UID. Then try your field calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach relies on Python dictionaries to store values from the table, and then uses an update cursor to populate the context score.

Paste the following into the interactive Python window when you have your table or feature class loaded into the active dataframe.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

table = "Site_Contect_1km_FINAL"
fields = ["UniqueIdentifier", "VegCondition", "Area_ha", "Context_Score"]

veg_conditions = defaultdict(dict)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        veg_conditions[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
    cur.reset()
    
    for row in cur:
        remnant_pct = veg_conditions[row[0]]["Remnant"] / sum(veg_conditions[row[0]].values())
        regrow_pct = veg_conditions[row[0]]["Regrowth"] / sum(veg_conditions[row[0]].values())
        
        if remnant_pct >= 0.3:
            score = 5 if remnant_pct > 0.75 else 4
        elif remnant_pct >= 0.1:
            score = 4 if regrow_pct >= 0.3 else 2
        else:
            score = 2 if regrow_pct >= 0.3 else 0
        
        cur.updateRow(row[:-1] + [score])
```

Comment: Thankyou so much that worked so well. I still haven't wrapped my head around cursors yet.